# bug writing colored text in assembly (8086) int 10h\ah =9

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I face a strange bug in assembly (8086) while using dosbox. 
I am trying to print text, colored green.
this is my main, when i called the function:

```
mov bl,2h                       ; set the color (green)
mov dx,OFFSET str_msg           ; set the string to print
call WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR
call NEW_LINE
```

and this is the function WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR

```
proc WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR 
mov ah,9  
mov cx,200  ; number of chars that will be painted
int 10h
int 21H 
ret
endp WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR
```

now, when i run the program, it's print the 'required' text, along with a long strig of 'dddddd'
i will really appreciate possible solutions.

Comment: `int 10h` prints the character in `AL`, `CX` times. Use `int 21h` for writing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can work if the count in CX is exactly equal to the actual length of the message. If CX has a number larger than the length of the message then BIOS will display the excess in whatever character code was in the AL register (that you forgot to setup)

I propose the following changes

```
mov bx,0002h          ; set the color (green) AND select page 0
mov dx,OFFSET str_msg ; set the string to print
call WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR
call NEW_LINE
```

and

```
proc WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR 
 mov ax,0920h  ;AH=Function number AL=Space character  
 mov cx,200  ; number of chars that will be painted
 int 10h     ;BIOS function 09h
 int 21H     ;DOS function 09h
 ret
endp WRITE_TEXT_IN_COLOR
```